# Get value from select tag on javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html-select

I want to change the `<img src>` with value from my `<select>`.

I have the next HTML code:

```
<img id="fotosel" /><br/>
<select id="cmbfotos" onchange="aplicarFoto()">
    <option value="gokussj3.jpg">Goku SSJ3</option>
    <option value="gokussj4.jpg">Goku SSJ4</option>
    <option value="gohanssj2.jpg">Gohan SSJ2</option>
    <option value="gotenks.jpg">Super Gotenks</option>
    <option value="krilin.jpg">Krilin</option>
</select>
```

and Javascript code:

```
 var fotosel = document.getElementById("fotosel");
    var cmb = document.getElementById("cmbfotos");
    function aplicarFoto(){
    fotosel.src = "fotos/"+cmb.options[cmb.selectedIndex].value;

   }
```

But that doesnt work. I made a test putting an `alert()` with `cmb.options[cmb.selectedIndex].value` and nothing appears.
Some guess? Thank you!

Comment: Seems to get the right value for me: http://jsfiddle.net/EMTPw/  Maybe something else on your page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `aplicarFoto()` function to:

```
function aplicarFoto(_src) {
    fotosel.src = 'fotos/' + _src;
}
```

and in your HTML:

```
<select id="cmbfotos" onchange="aplicarFoto(this.value)">
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: @Isaac - Probably because i missed the `'fotos/'` prefix. :-)

Comment: Thank you, but My problem was that I declared my variable outside the function... :) anyways your answer resolved my problem! :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<img id="fotosel" /><br/>
<select id="cmbfotos" onchange="aplicarFoto(this.value)">
    <option value="gokussj3.jpg">Goku SSJ3</option>
    <option value="gokussj4.jpg">Goku SSJ4</option>
    <option value="gohanssj2.jpg">Gohan SSJ2</option>
    <option value="gotenks.jpg">Super Gotenks</option>
    <option value="krilin.jpg">Krilin</option>
</select>
```

Javascipt :

```
    var fotosel = document.getElementById("fotosel");

     function aplicarFoto(elmImage){
        fotosel.src = "fotos/"+elmImage;
     }
```